# Pytessaract image_to_pdf_or_hocr function not working in AWS lambda

Tags: python, aws-lambda, tesseract, python-tesseract

I am using this repository to deploy tesseract as a lambda layer: https://github.com/bweigel/aws-lambda-tesseract-layer

The deployment works well and other functions that `pytesseract` has like: `image_to_string`, `image_to_data` also works well without any hiccups.

But, when I try to use `image_to_pdf_or_hocr` like this:

```py
pdf = pytesseract.image_to_pdf_or_hocr(f'/tmp/{file_name}/{page.number}.png', extension='pdf')
```

it does not work and throws error like:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/task/helpers/ocr_helper.py", line 36, in save_searchable_pdf
f'/tmp/{file_name}/{page.number}.png', extension='pdf')
File "/var/task/pytesseract/pytesseract.py", line 432, in image_to_pdf_or_hocr
return run_and_get_output(*args)
File "/var/task/pytesseract/pytesseract.py", line 289, in run_and_get_output
with open(filename, 'rb') as output_file:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/tess_6_hu78b0.pdf'
```

1. It says that the file `tess_6_hu78b0.pdf` does not exist. What does this mean? I have no file with `tess_6_hu78b0` name to begin with.
2. The path that I am passing to `image_to_pdf_or_hocr` function is 100% correct and an image is present there. I have confirmed and the same thing works on my local.

---

I have tried:

I found somewhere that I needed to install `libtesseract-dev` too. Hence, I modified my dockerfile as:

```
FROM lambci/lambda:build-python3.6
RUN sudo apt install tesseract-ocr
RUN sudo apt install libtesseract-dev
```

but unfortunately this too did not work.

Answer (score 4):

After 18 hours of hard work, I was finally able to figure it out.

It turns out that https://github.com/bweigel/aws-lambda-tesseract-layer is not bundled with all the necessary files for `pytesseract.image_to_pdf_or_hocr()` to run.

So what I did was, I build `leptonica` and `tesseract` from source and generated

- configs folder
- tessconfigs folder and
- pdf.tiff file

These required files are available here:
https://github.com/prameshbajra/tessdata

Inside https://github.com/bweigel/aws-lambda-tesseract-layer, under `ready-to-use` folder there is a directory named `amazonlinux-1`, and inside it, there is a folder named `tesseract/share/tessdata`. All you need to do is paste in the above listed files under this directory.

Just download [this](https://github.com/prameshbajra/tessdata) repo and replace the `tessdata` folder.

*Note: This tessdata is build with tesseract 4.1.1*

*I hope this helps future readers.
Happy coding.*

*Thank Benjamin Genz (@bweigel) for publishing this repo. You made our lives easier.*

Comment: @MohitDuklan sorry? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: After searching a lot for this, I realised that when installing tesseract from Conda in Python, those files aren't installed either, therefore no PDFs are generated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Adding this config argument fixed it for me, inspired by [this solution](https://github.com/madmaze/pytesseract/issues/106#issuecomment-605539554) :)

```
pytesseract.image_to_pdf_or_hocr("Image.png", extension="pdf", config = " -c tessedit_create_pdf=1")
```